# Is it possible to use snippets in Integrated Terminal area in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Cannot find how to set this option. I found user snippets setting for different languages, but Terminal is not there.

Comment: Highly doubt it as snippets seem to be for the editor, and the Integrated Terminal is just a passthrough to the shell defined by `terminal.integrated.shell.*`. Would you mind sharing what you're trying to do? It might be easier done with aliases or functions in the shell.

Comment: @wgj  Well, I just want to use snippet with opened in editor sql-file as parameter to run it to SQL Server through proprietary serv.cmd batch (with marco-preproccessing). So I cannot just do it like "Run query".

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like setting up a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) using the active editor (eg, ${file}) as the target to `serv.cmd` would be a good fit.

Comment: I could use snippets in the Integrated Terminal to call .php scripts with parameters.

Answer (score 5):

In v.1.28 you can send text from a key binding. Here is the link to the documentation
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-via-a-keybinding